# how to capture throttling exceptions for azure?

Tags: azure

I have the following code which uploads a blob to Azure:

```
var cloudStorageAccount = await GetCloudStorageAccount(connectionString);
var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var containerRef = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blobRef = containerRef.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
await blobRef.UploadTextAsync(fileContent);
```

I need to add code which captures throttling exceptions.  For example, if my code above is being called in a loop and the number of attempted writes exceeds the configured limit in Azure, then some type of 429 (Too Many Requests) error will be thrown. How can I catch that exception?  Is there any time of special error class for that like AzureThrottleException?  Or can you recommend another way of handling this exception state?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a try StorageException, all the exceptions can be found here: [common error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes), [blob error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes).

And for the throttling, it's error code is 503 as per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-performance-checklist#blobs) -> `Throttling/ServerBusy` section.

So you can write your code as below:

```
try
{
//your code
}
catch(StorageException ex)
{
     var errorcode = ex.RequestInformation.ErrorCode;
     var statuscode = ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode.ToString();
     Console.WriteLine("the error code is: "+errorcode);
     Console.WriteLine("the status code is: "+statuscode);
}
```